¿Como incluir imagenes al crear una libreria en Angular?
Estoy tratando de crear una pequeña librería con variables y funciones en Angular. Pero al tratar de incluir imágenes en la carpeta assets de la librería, no las reconoce. Es decir, si creo una variable apuntando a la ruta de la imagen dentro de la carpeta assets de la librería y la invoco dentro de un proyecto, esta termina apuntando a la ruta de la imagen del proyecto local, no a la que está incluida en la librería.
Mi ruta de la librería esta así:

También he agregado la línea necesaria al ng-package.json de la propia librería:

La manera en que llamo la ruta de la imagen en la librería, es de esta manera, para luego solo llamar la variable en el proyecto:


Coloca las imágenes en src/lib/assets dentro de tu librería. Luego, en tu archivo angular.json, asegúrate de que la configuración para los assets incluya esa carpeta:
"assets": [
  "src/lib/assets"
]

Cuando referencies las imágenes en tus componentes, usa rutas relativas como assets/my-image.png. Por ejemplo:
const imagePath = 'assets/my-image.png';

